# Возвращение из метода конкретного класса, реализующего интерфейс

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Почему не получается в классе i2_c1 реализовать getI с возвращаемым значением конкретного класса? Ведь этот конкретный класс реализует интерфейс, и как я думал, компилятору будет всё равно, что возвращается, главное чтобы интерфейс был реализован. Может быть я делаю что то не так? Вот код:

```
interface i1
{
    int f();
}

class i1_c1 : i1
{
    public int f() { return 1; }
}

class i1_c2 : i1
{
    public int f() { return 2; }
}

interface i2
{
    i1 getI();
}

class i2_c1 : i2
{
    public i1_c1 getI()
    {
        return new i1_c1();
    }
}
```

Этот код компилируется с ошибкой:
Ошибка CS0738   'i2_c1" не реализует член интерфейса "i2.getI()". 'i2_c1.getI()" не может реализовать "i2.getI()", потому что не имеет соответствующего возвращаемого типа "i1".

UPD.: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему я не могу установить возвращаемый тип как конкретный класс, реализующий интерфейс, который возвращается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class i2_c1 : i2
{
    public i1 getI()
    {
        return new i1_c1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, это убирает ошибку, спасибо. Но мне бы хотелось узнать, почему нельзя возвращать конкретный класс?

Comment: @Leemellaret Потому что сигнатуры методов должны совпадать.

Comment: Они же, по идее, совпадают. Указанный возвращаемый тип реализует же интерфейс.

Comment: @Leemellaret Сигнатура интерфейса позволяет возвращать любого наследника интерфейса i1. Вот накидаете вы 10 классов i1_c1...i1_c10, и если все они реализуют i1, то метод  `public i1 getI()` может вернуть любого из них, а метод `public i1_c1 getI()` может вернуть только i1_c1 (и его наследников). Поэтому методы `public i1 getI()`  и `public i1_c1 getI()` являются разными методами с разными сигнатурами.

Comment: понял, спасибо!